# PHP - Cron Jobs that sync data from an external API. How's my methodology?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, queue, synchronization

I was after some feedback on a PHP/MySQL based web app that I'm in the process of developing. The app is a member-based site which uses a local database to store data for each user by day. This data comes from an external API and needs to be automatically synced daily so that my local DB has up-to-date data. This is the methodology I have in mind:

#### I have 2 Cron Jobs:

1. The Queue Builder
2. The Queue Worker

#### ..and 3 database tables:

1. User Data (stores whatever user data I have so far, if any).
2. User Details (a list of all members which includes users that I don't have data for as yet, aka new signups).
3. The Processing Queue

***The Queue Builder*** is a PHP script that will run via Cron at regular intervals. It will:

- Compare the **User Details** and **User Data** tables to determine which new users I don't have any data for yet. For these users, it will build a list of URLs starting from 1/1/11 until the present day and insert them into **The Processing Queue** table (this is because I wish to have data from the start of the year for all my users).
- Analyse the **User Data** table to find when each user's data was last synced, and build a list of URLs from the last synced date until the current day. These will also be inserted into **The Processing Queue** table.

This way **The Processing Queue** table will contain a list of all the URLs that need to be queried.

***The Queue Worker*** is also a PHP Cron script that will:

- Select the first 20 items in **The Processing Queue** table, get their contents using CURL multi, error-check, and then delete the first 20 rows from the table. I'm breaking it up into 20 URLs at a time because if I process too many URLs the script may hang or my host may come knocking on my door equipped with a shotgun.

This will also run regularly via a Cron job, so the idea is that data-syncing should be automated and users should have up-to-date data. My questions are:

1. What are the general thoughts on my methodology? Are there any side effects to doing it this way? I'm a hobbyist developer without a CS background so always keen on gaining criticism and learning about best practices! =)
2. When a new user signs up, I plan on giving them a "your data can take xx minutes to sync" while redirecting them to Getting Started resources etc. This is probably okay for my initial release, but further down the track I'd like to refine it so users get an email notification when syncing is ready or can see a % progress. Does my current solution accomodate this easily? Or will I have headaches down the track?

Opinions are appreciated! Many, MANY thanks in advance - I hope I have explained this clearly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best advise I can give you is this:  KISS!!   No, I'm not being over-affectionate, this stands for "Keep it simple, stupid!" and is arguably a very important engineering principle.  With this in mind, the first question I'd ask is "why cron?"  Would it be possible to have all of these tasks run in real-time when users sign up?  If yes, I'd say go with this for now and don't bother with cron.  If you do decide to go with the cron module I'd recommend the following:

- Consider using a lock file to prevent multiple instances of your script running at the same time.  For example, if you run the script every 5 minutes, and each time it runs the script takes 10 minutes to complete then the multiple instances could interfere with each other.
- Using curl multi will probably put more strain on your target server than making single requests in a loop, if you want to be polite to the target server then it's probably best to use single requests and have a short sleep in the loop.
- If you only process 20 jobs at a time and your service is very popular you could end up with a permanently extending work queue.  For example, if you're acquiring 40 tasks an hour and only processing 20 tasks an hour, you'll never reach the end of the queue and the queue will never complete.

HTH.

Comment: Hey Robin, many thanks for your reply.

I can certainly initiate the process when a user signs up, however I wish to acquire new data every night at 12am (for the previous day), so that's why I'm leaning towards a Cron Job. Are there better/easier alternatives?

Thanks for the lock file tip - I'll certainly do that to prevent multiple jobs from initiating. :)

You raise a great point about the permanently extending work queue! My process is essentially just CURL getting a text string from a bunch of different URLs so I should be alright, though it's great to know the potential pitfalls.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like a cron job is required, I reckon this is probably the easiest solution.  The only other advice I have is the same I gave you before - KISS!

Comment: Thanks Robin, what's the simplest method of incorporating the email notifications once a user signs up? I'm thinking adding a "status" column to the User Details table and tracking that may be the way to go - though it does seem complex!

Comment: How are you handling API failure?  What if your cron fires but API is down and now a days worth of data is not imported?  Does the script check that the previous day ran successfully?